# AWS SES Not Delivering

Tags: amazon-web-services, outlook, office365, amazon-ses

I am currently using AWS SES to send emails to my users. However, it appears that my users who use outlook / Microsoft's Business Email System are not receiving my emails. SES also tells me that I have no bounces too.

The user's email has `{name}.onmicrosoft.com`  on it.

How can I go about resolving this?

EDIT: Found out that the key phrase "password" is a root cause for the email being blocked and not showing up at all. Not sure how to combat this as I am sending a password reset email.

Thanks

Comment: Check spam folders maybe?

Comment: I have asked them to check SPAM and any sort of filtered inbox, but to no avail.

Comment: Did you run through the steps at [Amazon SES Delivery problems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/troubleshoot-delivery.html)?

Comment: Check this discussion
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/674065/emails-from-amazon-ses-not-delivered.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've gone through the thread and I have both SPF and DKIM added as the post suggests. However still to no avail.

Comment: Added an EDIT, figured out one issue.